# php class $this->regex not working

Tags: php

I am having an issue inside my class where the `static private` variable is being used inside a function does not work. But it does work when the regex is directly inside it.

```
class Object{
  static private $regex = "/\w+|\-\d+/";

  //does not work (NULL)
  public function tokenize($text){
    preg_match_all($this->regex, $text, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
  }

  //works
  public function tokenize($text){
    $regex = "/\w+|\-\d+/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
  }
}

$o = New Object;
$o->tokenize("test text -123");
```

Comment: Please start accepting answers. I'm not talking about this question in particular, but most your questions, where you have good answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

To access the `private static` property from non-`static` context within your class as you are trying to do this right now, you should access it with

```
self::$regex
```

Or you could redeclare your `$regex` property to be only `private` (non-`static`) and then you will be able to access it as `$this->regex`

Answer (score 1):

You declared the regex var as `static` (and it's missing a $, but I think that's a different mistake). Static vars cannot be accessed as object attributes (`$this->regex`), but it works as $regex, because you are defining it right in the scope of the second function.

So you can fix the problem by removing the `static` modifier, if you want to use it as an attribute. Otherwise, you can use `self::$regex` or `Object::$regex` to access it statically from anywhere inside the object (the latter also outside the object, but only if it's public).

Comment: yea, the `static private regex` was a mistake, fixed it to `static private $regex` but doing `preg_match_all($regex...` instead of `$this->regex` with `static` does not work. removing `static` does though

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify. If you really want to keep it static and access it, you may use Object::$regex